# Which planet or moon has all resources that can be used to sustain life in a controlled biosphere?

Tags: planet, natural-satellites, terrestrial-planets, space-debris

Now that we are making it to Mars, continuing onward, in an effort for humanity to civilize other planets, not just setting up residential colonies, but to mine minerals and carry on geological and scientific research, which planet or moon has all resources that can be used to sustain life in a controlled biosphere?

And how can the available resources on that body be converted to suit human requirement?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about Astronomy and it should belong on [SpaceExploration's StackExchange](http://space.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Eduardo  Serra : then can you please move it to spaceexploration's stackexchange !!!

Comment: It'll be moved if five people agree on it, one of the great things about stack exchange is that it's controlled by it's own community.

Comment: Otherwise don't you have any input to make?

Comment: I think technology right now doesn't allow for a viable plan but in the future we won't have to depend on any of the planet's resources. Self-sustainable life inside a bio-dome would be the way to go, and any planet where natural disasters like massive storms, earthquakes, active volcanoes and the like are uncommon enough should do the trick.

Comment: As the question stands, it would be appropriate for Space, except that the scope is too broad.

Comment: The only answer to this that I came to so far is the moon. As it has frozen ice on it's poles. Which means that theoretically electrolysis could be performed to produce energy, powering the biosphere, operating 3D printers to build stuff, or even space crafts which need much less escape velocity on the moon due to 6x less gravity than earth's.

Answer (score 2):

No known planet except Earth can be colonized by a human civilization. There are at least three serious issues: temperatures at around 300K, an atmosphere of appropirate pressure, and damaging cosmic radiation (low gravity is also a worry for long-term human presence). Minerals are less of a problem (and water can be synthesized). Mars and the Moon are close enough to the Sun for pressurized greenhouses to provide an environment where humans could stay without space suit. However, the problem of cosmic radiation remains and such "biospheres" must forever dependent on supportive technology. Venus's inhospitable atmosphere makes it completely unfeasible.

Using robots to mine planets and moons in the Solar system is certainly a realistic and interesting option. Sending humans there is very expensive and not necessarily sensible. Moreover, it is not clear whether humanity should send any live (including microorganisms) to such places, as this would inevitably forever change their nature (like sending rabbits/cats to Australia); all ongoing space missions are sterilized before being sent on their way.

Comment: what about Enceledus, Europa and titan ?

Comment: All too far from the Sun, hence too cold. Europa is hot because of volcanic activity driven by tidal forcing, but this also makes it inhospitable.

Comment: @Walter I'm not sure why you tagged me - unless I'm missing or forgetting something, I have not participated in this discussion...

Comment: Mars is also -128`c at night

Comment: @Moriarty sorry. I thought you sanctioned that edit.